# How can I add .html at the end if pathbrowser value?

Tags: aem

I have a multifield in dialog of component with two other fields as `pageName` and `pagePath` and sling:resourceType of `pagePath` is `pathbrowser`.

I made a Sling model to read values and it is returning values properly.

Now the problem is I want to return pagePath into an anchor tag.

My HTML code is :

```
<sly data-sly-use.info=“MyProject.models.SubPagesModel” />
<ul data-sly-list.pageList=“${info.subPages}” >
<li><a href=“${pageList.pagePath}”>${pageList.pageName}</a></li>
</ul>
</sly>
```

But the pathbrowser is returning value with only the page name without `.html` extension. What changes should I make so that I can give it as a link to the page? How can I add `.html` extension to pathbrowser value?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
   <sly data-sly-use.info=“MyProject.models.SubPagesModel” />
     <ul data-sly-list.pageList=“${info.subPages}” >
      <li><a href=“${pageList.pagePath @ extension = 'html'}”>${pageList.pageName}</a></li>
    </ul>
   </sly>
```

See the sample We-retail implementation: /apps/weretail/components/content/heroimage/heroimage.html